# Enhanced Ecommerce Add To Cart Event Tracking Is Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

For track Add to cart event use below code but code is not working please help me to fix out.

------Not working-----

```
ga('require', 'ec');

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery("#AddToCart").click(function(e) {
            ga('ec:addProduct', {
                    'id': 'P12345',
                    'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt',
                    'category': 'Apparel',
                    'brand': 'Google',
                    'variant': 'black',
                    'price': '29.20',
                    'coupon': 'APPARELSALE',
                    'quantity': 1
            });

            ga('send', 'event', 'Event-Category', 'Add To Cart', 'Event-Lable','Event-Value'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Would be easier if you will show some more code. First: check console in developer tools in browser. I guess there will be some errors (if for example ga object is not defined properly etc.)

Comment: Enhanced eCommerce and Add to cart event are different things. You can track enhanced eCommerce under conversions and events under events. I see code of both the things above. Can you please clarify what exactly is not working?